# Using existing Win7 OS in new build

Tags: windows-7

I'm planning to build a new PC & want to use the win 7 disc/OS I am currently using in my present build.  I will be reusing the current HDD's, RAM, PSU & vid card with a new MOBO & CPU.  I'm guessing M$ is going to try to jerk me around when I attempt to "activate" the new build/installation.  Am I likely to run into issues reusing this OS?

Comment: You will require a new license but you can copy your installation with various disk imaging software that support restoring that image to new hardware.

Comment: Are you looking to keep your existing Windows installation on the hard drive, or use the same drive but reformat and install a fresh copy of Windows?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a tool called "sysprep". Instructions can be found here:http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/135077-windows-7-installation-transfer-new-computer.html

Comment: Sysprep is for an OEM building a system that'll be delivered to a customer.  You don't need it just to transfer a Windows license to another computer of your own.

Comment: @PandaLion98: I edited your answer to expand it and address that it is likely to be seen as a link-only answer.  However, Wyzard's comment and Citizen's answer seem to indicate that sysprep may not be required.  I rolled the edit back since I'm not sure of the facts.  You might want to double check.  If it's not required, delete or modify your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your operating system is tied to the hardware platform you can identify this by looking for an OEM license sticker somewhere on the laptop or desktop.  This version of OS cannot be used on another hardware platform.  If you re-install this OEM OS on your system it will ask you to activate it over the Internet, if it is already registered as active from Microsoft they will display an 800 number based upon your country for you to call into.

The automated system will ask you to read the license key into the phone and via voice recognition will issue you a key to use for activation.  If you have difficulty using the technology, you can request an operator.  This system will allow you to activate the OS on multiple systems but the EULA that you agree to by using the system does not allow it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies.  My current system is one I built about 8 years ago around an ASUS 2 core mobo.  I originally ran XP on it, then bought 7 about 3 years ago & installed that.  I'm guessing that since the OS was not preinstalled on a "Dell" or similar, I should simply be able to install it on the new build & activate it?  Since I'll be reusing all but the old mobo & cpu, the old machine will no longer be operating, i.e., the OS will be installed on only 1 PC.